# Calendar Event Insert fails "Login Required" C#/REST

Tags: c#, events, calendar, oauth-2.0

I have created a web application that is intended to give people an opportunity to schedule an appointment with me and I use business logic to validate the time is valid.  I keep all of my appointments on Google Calendar.  So I went to the Google API Console created Web Application Project. I got my client_id and secret.  I am able to retrieve an access token just fine.  I even have the refresh token and built logic to automatically refresh the access token and that works fine.  I use this token to retrieve a list of calendar events and that works fine.  I then use the token to do an insert of a new calendar event and I get an error. First the code:

```
 public CalendarEvent InsertCalendarEvent(CalendarEditArgs args)
 {
 string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(args.CalendarId) + "/events?&key=" + args.APIKey;

 Web.SetUpPost(url, null, true, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(args.Event), null, null, new { Name = "Authorization", Value = "Bearer " + args.AccessToken }, new { Name = "X-JavaScript-User-Agent", Value = "Easy SPS" });
 string response = null;

 try
 {
 response = Web.GetResponse(); 
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CalendarEvent>(response);
 }
 catch(WebException e)
 {
 response = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
 throw new Exception(response, e);
 }


 }

 public void SetUpPost(string url, string parameters, bool json, string body, string clientKey, string clientSecret, params object[] data)
 {
 if (body != null && parameters != null)
 throw new InvalidOperationException("You cannot submit a request body and parameters at the same time.");
 request =  WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;


 if (!json)
 {
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 }
 else
 {
 request.ContentType = "application/json";
 }
 request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
 request.Method = "POST";
 request.Referer = "https://www.easy-sps.com";
 request.KeepAlive = true;
 byte[] bytes = null;
 if (body != null || parameters != null)
 {
 bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body == null ? parameters : body);
 request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
 System.IO.Stream os = request.GetRequestStream();
 os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
 os.Close();
 }
 else
 {
 request.ContentLength = 0;

 }

 if (data != null)
 {
 foreach (var dataObject in data)
 {
 PropertyInfo prop = dataObject.GetType().GetProperties()[0];
 PropertyInfo prop2 = dataObject.GetType().GetProperties()[1];
 request.Headers.Add(prop.GetValue(dataObject, null).ToString(), prop2.GetValue(dataObject, null).ToString());
 }
 }

 }
 }

The error I get:

 {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Couple of notes I am not actually making use of the clientkey and client secret because they are used to fetch the token not use it.  To retrieve the token, I did have to login into google with offline access (I know this worked because Google indicated I was granting access to the Calendar even when I'm not online).  I went on to the google playground and there I can get it to work but not here.  I have tried to find a difference between what I posted and what it posted and I can't find anything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Been stuck with zero progress for over a week now and as we know Google doesn't support it's developers directly, just through its forums and I simple cannot find my situation in those forums with stuff that I haven't already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides a .Net wrapper around calendar api. See [.NET Client Library Developer's Guide.](https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs)

Comment: Yeah I am trying to avoid using the wrapper at this point.  Hoping to continue to use RESTful calls to get this done.

Comment: Source code of the wrapper is available. So you can digging through it.

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that I just couldn't pinpoint the difference between what I was doing and what they were doing ultimately.

Comment: In this case I recommend you to write what you want with the wrapper. Than by using Fiddler and any comparison tool compare http requests/responses between two implementations.

Comment: Why would you _not_ use an API wrapper designed for a google product by google?

Comment: I simply chose to use the REST Methods to call their API, which is also a product designed by google for google.  But its buggy and the documentation isn't accurate, I feared the worst for their .NET API honestly, and since google doesn't offer paid support if you get in a jam I really want as few layers of google code between me and them.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by putting the access token in the url  "access_token=".  Why it works in the URL but not in the Header is beyond me.